# C++ Matrix Addition

Tags: c++

I tried to write a C++ program that adds two (m x n) matrices. Here's the code:

```
/* Program: Add two (m x n) matrices */

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#define n 5

using namespace std;
void inputMatrix (int MatX[][n],int m, int n0);
void outputMatrix (int MatX[][n],int m, int n0);
void addMatrix (int A[][n],int B[][n],int C[][n],int m, int n0);

main()
{
    /* Input Matrix Dimensions */
    int m,n0;
    cout<<"Enter No. of (Rows,Columns) in Matrix: ";
    cin>>m>>n0;
    /* Initialize Matrices */
    int MatA[m][n],MatB[m][n],MatC[m][n];
    /* Input Matrix Elements */
    cout<<"############### Matrix A ###############"<<endl;
    inputMatrix(MatA,m,n0);
    cout<<"############### Matrix B ###############"<<endl;
    inputMatrix(MatB,m,n0);
    /* Compute & Display Result */
    addMatrix(MatA,MatB,MatC,m,n0);
    cout<<"########################################"<<endl;
    outputMatrix(MatC,m,n0);
    getch();
}
void inputMatrix (int MatX[][n],int m, int n0)
{
        for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j<n0; j++)
            {
                cout<<"Element["<<i<<","<<j<<"] Value: ";
                cin>>MatX[i][j];
            }
}
void outputMatrix (int MatX[][n],int m, int n0)
{
    cout<<"########### Resultant Matrix ###########"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<n0; j++)
            cout<<"X["<<i<<","<<j<<"] = "<<MatX[i][j]<<'\t';
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
void addMatrix (int A[][n],int B[][n],int C[][n],int m, int n0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j] ;
}
/*
1. Here, matrices A,B,C are 'm x n', but evaluations are made for 'm x n0'.
    int MatA[m][n],MatB[m][n],MatC[m][n];
   where user chooses dimensions of matrices (m x n0) to work upon.
   This is because we have to initialize a matrix as A[][n] atleast. So we need atleast one parameter to be fixed for the compiler to allocate space.
2. Also, no Array values are returned explicitly.
    void inputMatrix (...)
    void outputMatrix (...)
    void addMatrix (...)
*/`
```

The program works fine.
My doubts are:

1. When working with Matrix A,B,C how do functions inputMatrix(),outputMatrix(),addMatrix work on MatA,MatB,MatC?
   Do they have separate copies? Do they work on the original addresses directly?
2. What should I do if I want to implement the program with matrix calculations of sizes 'm x n' (not 'm x n0'), where m,n are input by user?

Comment: ***where m,n are input by user?*** Eventually you will be taught how to use vectors and other suitable containers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will answer both questions mentioned separately as follows:

1. Yes, passing arrays to functions is just like passing their original addresses.
2. You will use Dynamic Allocation and work on heap rather than stack.

For completeness, here is a simple example on Dynamic Allocation:

```
int** mat = new int*[m];
for (int = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    mat[i] = new int[n];
}
```